# Make condition evaluation silently

Tags: bash, if-statement

I need to check if I installed a software by my script, the code snipe is shown below

```
if ! command -v PackageABC
then
   echo "Please install PackageABC"
fi
```

The first line always print out the root information for the PackageABC. How can I make the condition evaluation silently?

I've try to add & in the end `if ! command -v PackageABC &` but it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is the standard output and/or stderr. You should discard both, one way to do that is to redirect them to null using `[command] > /dev/null 2>&1` (see [How to redirect stderr](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/))

```
if ! command -v PackageABC > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    echo "Please install PackageABC"; 
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Redirect your output, like this:

```
if ! command -v PackageABC > /dev/null
then
   echo "Please install PackageABC"
fi
```

you can even make it one line:

```
[ ! $(command -v PackageABC >/dev/null) ] && echo "Please install PackageABC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, however below's one way checking whether a package is installed or not, without the unwanted output of your approach :

```
if rpm -qa | grep -q package_name 
then 
  echo "Package is installed"
else
  echo "Package not installed"
```

Comment: This is distro specific and not portable